# netgraph : set position of labels

Tags: r

I need help to set netgaph in R. I would like to set the position of treatment labels in network meta-analysis with a visualisation in circle.

Some titles of treatment labels are too closer between them and we cannot read them.

I don't know to use `xpos.labels` and `ypos.labels` described in value part in help on netgraph in R. It does not work.

```
netgraph(net2, seq = net2$seq, labels=net2$trts,
         points=TRUE, 
         cex.points=t2$size_pt, col.points = "lightblue4", pch.points = 19,
         cex=0.5, 
         thickness="se.fixed", 
         scale=.85, offset = 0.025,
         number.of.studies=T, cex.number.of.studies=1, 
         col.number.of.studies = "White", 
         bg.number.of.studies = "Black",
         col.multiarm = "grey",
         col = "Black", plastic =F, ypos.labels=vec_y_modif)
Warning messages:
1: In plot.window(...) : "ypos.labels" is not a graphical parameter
2: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) :
  "ypos.labels" is not a graphical parameter
3: In title(...) : "ypos.labels" is not a graphical parameter
```

May I ask you some help please?

Comment: Could you please post a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the doc you should use ypos and not ypos.labels

```
 netgraph(net2, seq = net2$seq, labels=net2$trts,
         points=TRUE, 
         cex.points=t2$size_pt, col.points = "lightblue4", 
   pch.points = 19,
          cex=0.5, 
          thickness="se.fixed", 
     scale=.85, offset = 0.025,
     number.of.studies=T, cex.number.of.studies=1, 
     col.number.of.studies = "White", 
     bg.number.of.studies = "Black",
     col.multiarm = "grey",
     col = "Black", plastic =F, ypos=vec_y_modif)
```